# child buttons of Reusable UITableViewCells not allowing me to update tag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am attempting to update the tag of buttons within a reusable UITableViewCell. For the first 5-8 cells there is no issue with setting the tag as these cells have not been "reused" yet from my understanding. Once the UI does have to reuse a cell, it no longer allows me to change the tag or set the tag of the button. What am I missing?

```
UITableViewCell *cell =[tblPlaces dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mainTableViewCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"mainTableViewCell"];
}

[[cell viewWithTag:107] setTag:indexPath.section];
```

Comment: Where are you calling this? Just anywhere in your code? or in your cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: It is in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function. The cell is actually from my UITableView in my storyboard if that helps. And I am initializing the proper way I believe. I also edited the code block above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't working because you're changing the tag of your button with the first cells that are created. When you dequeue a cell to be reused, it's button's tag has already been changed from before, so it is no longer 107, it's whatever the old index was.

I would consider subclassing UITableViewCell and adding the button as a property of your subclass. That way you would have direct access to it and wouldn't need to use tags.

Edit:

Here's a really simple example of all you really need to do:

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *myButton;
@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Create and add your button in here, or set it equal to the one you create in Interface Builder
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: ahh makes sense. I knew there was a small thing I was missing. Do you have any clear examples of subclassing UITableViewCell for this particular purpose?

Comment: Thanks! Subclassing worked great for me actually. It gave me complete control without relying on one tag value for manipulation.